# React Native Async Storage

Tags: sharedpreferences, react-native

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

I am using the above package. it was working fine 2 hours ago. but suddenly stop working.no issue or warning is there.

I am using Aysncstorge in my app to save a value. it was working fine. her is my code.

```
  const Authorize = dispatch => async () =>{
        console.log("calledddd")
            try{
              let islogin = await  AsyncStorage.getItem('islogin')
               console.log(islogin)
            }catch(error){
                console.log(error)
            }
       console.log("called last")
    }
```

I also tried it like this.

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem('islogin').then((islogin) => {
     console.log(islogin)
}).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error)
 })
```

Comment: You didn't say what the problem was. Are you getting an error?

Comment: By the way, AsyncStorage seems to be deprecated.

Comment: it is stuck there. no error or warnning

Comment: import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' this is the official package for AyycnStorage. it looks like it is waiting for the value to get. and takes up 5 min. @jperl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it from the following package:

> `@react-native-community/async-storage`

Enjoy!!!